# Use Tablesorter to filter by selected option's selects in a column

Tags: javascript, jquery, tablesorter

I use the plugin jQuery Tablesorter by Mottie for a long time and it's very useful but today I have a issue. I want to filter my table by the selected options of the selects in one of the columns. The sort works but not the filter.

This is the code HTML :

```html
<table id="tableau-programmes" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="donnees tablesorter">
 <thead>
  <tr class="bg-vert-2">
   <th>Programme</th><th>No</th><th>Département</th><th>CP</th><th>Ville</th><th>Agence</th><th>Association</th>
  </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
  <tr id="18">
   <td><a href="programme-neuf-18.php">Bornéo</a></td>
   <td>44</td><td>Loire-Atlantique</td>
   <td>44100</td><td>Nantes</td>
   <td>
    <select class="centre-profit">
     <option value="0">...</option>
     <option value="2" selected="selected" class="bg-vert-4">Agence de Saint-Nazaire</option>
     <option value="1">Agence de Nantes</option>
    </select>
   </td>
   <td><span class="c-vert">Oui</span></td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="17" class="bg-vert-4">
   <td><a href="programme-neuf-17.php">Erdréa</a></td>
   <td>44</td>
   <td>Loire-Atlantique</td>
   <td>44300</td>
   <td>Nantes</td>
   <td>
    <select class="centre-profit">
     <option value="0">...</option>
     <option value="2" selected="selected" class="bg-vert-4">Agence de Saint-Nazaire</option>
     <option value="1">Agence de Nantes</option></select></td>
   <td><span class="c-vert">Oui</span></td>
  </tr>
  ...
 </tbody>
</table>
```

This is the code js :

```js
$(function(){
 var nom_prog_preselect = (id_prog_preselect > 0) ? $("tr#"+id_prog_preselect).children('td:first').text() : '';
 $.tablesorter.addParser({ 
   id: 'txt_select', 
   is: function(s) { 
     return false;
   }, 
   format: function(s, table, cell) {
    return $(cell).find('select').children('option:selected').text() || s;
   },
   parsed: true,
   type: 'text' 
 });
 $(".tablesorter").tablesorter({
  widgets:['zebra','stickyHeaders','filter']
  ,headers: {
   5: { sorter:"txt_select", filter:false }
  }
  ,initialized: function (table, filter, apply) {
   $.tablesorter.setFilters( table, [nom_prog_preselect,'','','','','',''], true);
  }
 });
});
```

Is there anyone who can help me please ? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating a custom "txt_select" parser, load the [`parser-input-select.js` file](https://github.com/Mottie/tablesorter/blob/master/js/parsers/parser-input-select.js) provided with the [fork of tablesorter](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/).

That file has two select parsers:

- `'select'` - Stores the selected value
- `'select-text'` - Stores the selected text

and some extra code that is needed when the select value changes to update the internal cache.

Comment: Thanks Mottie for your help and reactivity. I've tried whith this parser but it still filters by all the values in the selects but not only the selected values. You can see my code at https://demo.extranet.immo/tests/tmp.html.

Comment: Update your version of tablesorter, you're using v2.10.8 and the repo is on v2.25.0 now.

Comment: I've updated the plugin but it doesn't resolve the issue :( I've tried with Jquery 2.0.0 but it 's the same result.

Comment: Please update [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/856bzzeL/766/) to show me the issue, or maybe it will help you find the problem :)

Comment: Thank you very much Mottie. Basicaly there is'nt the ".filtered" class in my css file (.tablesorter .filtered {display:none}). It now works well.